# Problems with ti.imagefactory

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

in practice after taking a picture using the function

```
Titanium.Media.showCamera({
        success : function(event) {
            var image = event.media;

            var winTest = Alloy.createController('inputContentPost', {
                'img' : image
            }).getView();
            winTest.open();

        },
```

I call another controller to which the step imagines me back from the function and try to work it as shown in the following code:

```
var ImageFactory = require('ti.imagefactory');

    var args = $.args;
    var img = args.img;

    var f = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(img);
    var blob = f.read();
    //imageViewTransformed.image = blob;

    var newBlob = ImageFactory.imageAsResized(blob, {
        width : 1024,
        height : 1024,
        quality : ImageFactory.QUALITY_HIGH
    });
```

the problem is that returns me the error sequent

```
[ERROR] :  Script Error {
[ERROR] :      column = 2779;
[ERROR] :      line = 1;
[ERROR] :      message = "-[TiBlob hasPrefix:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1292da580";
```

all this only on iOS , while Android- there are no mistakes and everything works.
You have any solution for me ??? Thank you

Comment: A helpful thing to do would be to run your app with `--skip-js-minify` so that you can have a more meaningful stack trace.

Comment: This module is deprecated by Appcelerator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your "other file" args.img is the blob data already (it references  event.media). There's no need to read from the file system. Try this:

```
var newBlob = ImageFactory.imageAsResized(args.img, {
    width : 1024,
    height : 1024,
    quality : ImageFactory.QUALITY_HIGH
});
```

BTW, I'd also suggest you avoid creating variables you don't need. For example:

```
Titanium.Media.showCamera({
    success : function(event) {
        Alloy.createController('inputContentPost', {
            img : event.media
        }).getView().open();

    },
```